# How can I access an Android app's ActionBar?

Tags: android, adb, android-uiautomator

As part of our android application testing, we need to access the navigation button on the ActionBar.  I haven't found anything in uiautomater or the adb docs that suggest a way to access it.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you provide any sample code (per [SO's quality question guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) that shows what you have so far so that we can lead you to an appropriate solution?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do, but https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html this explains the ActionBar pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a third party library you can try Robotium to solve this and a lot more.  When I test this I use `solo.clickOnImage(0);`. This has been a reliable way for me to test that button.  Also, if you want to make sure that it takes you to the right screen you can use `solo.waitForActivity(MyActivity.class,1000);`.

Answer (score 0):

My english is not good to understand your question, However for actionBar

According to I understand,
 `android:showAsAction` attribute to determine how it should be displayed in the ActionBar

Comment: As far as I understood, user3100616 needs a way to access the ActionBar for automation, so your answer is not answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your test class is derived from InstrumentationTestCase, you can press the navigation button this way

```
getInstrumentation().invokeMenuActionSync(activity, android.R.id.home, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'uiautomatorviewer' option through cmd and find out if you can view any text or description for that object in action bar which you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
   mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
   UiObject ActivateButton = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector()
            .text("Activate"));     // Replace with the text on ur Action Button
   if(ActivateButton.exists())
        ActivateButton.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import androidx.test.uiautomator.Until.findObject
import com.name.app.BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID

private val device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())

        val logout = device.wait(findObject(By.res(APPLICATION_ID, "logout")), 500)
        logout.click()
```